# Diodes for mixer design

Tags: diodes, design, pins, schottky, mixer

For a diode ring mixer, how should I choose the types of diodes? I've seen Schottky diodes as the primary choice. but why not PIN diodes?

What diode aspects should I consider when designing a mixer?

Thanks!

Comment: The first part of this page addresses a desirable diode model https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/146369/Mixer_Musings.pdf

Comment: PIN diodes are slow and resistive, two things you don't want for a mixer.

Comment: @glen_geek thanks for the paper. It explains some! This paper mainly relate didoes to IMD products. But IMD is not the only spec to design a mixer, am I right? I am wondering what happens if I sacrifice some linearity.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for the reply. Yes, switching time of PIN diodes is longer compared to Schottky diodes. Aren't GaAs PIN diodes pretty fast? Also how could I relate it to mixer performance? In the paper glen_geek posted, it talks about intermodulation performance. How about other important features like image rejection/LO rejection? (Conversion loss should be higher for PIN diodes as they are more resistive. Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: Why do you want to build your own mixer when you can buy for not a lot of money a pretty good one? Start there and then you can evaluate why it's not working and where to go for what you need. Have a look at the MiniCircuits and M/A-Com application notes for mixers and the selection of mixers available from the big distributors.

Comment: Linearity is often important, especially where the RF port sees a wide bandwidth. Good port-to-port isolation might benefit from matched diodes. These diode rings want significant local oscillator power that you'd like to suppress at the RF port & IF port. You **do** want fast-switching diodes with fast reverse recovery time.